# CredentialUnavailableException: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity

I was getting this error when I run my application in visual studio.
CredentialUnavailableException: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did not above error message when when I run below command in cmd in windows.

az login --tenant TenantId

Replace Tenant Id with your tenant id.